# No hacer funcionar un sitio web en apache con debian 11

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Tengo un dominio creado en linode.com de Akamai Cloud, esta instalado Debian 11, Apache2, Mariadb y PHP. syscon32.cl, solo sale el formulario de Logion, pero al ingresar las credenciales, no hace nada, no avanza al Dashboard.
Linode no acepta los archivos .htaccess, leyendo la documentación de apache, recomienda no usar los archivos .htacces, por ende lo eliminé, y agregue, los datos del .htacces al archivo de configuracion del sistema apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@servpc.cl
ServerName syscon32.cl
ServerAlias www.syscon32.cl
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/syscon32.cl/public_html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/syscon32.cl_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/syscon32.cl_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =syscon32.cl [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.syscon32.cl
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

```
<Directory /var/www/html/syscon32.cl/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

Me pueden ayudar por favor.

Comment: Linode es un Cloud que ofrece VPS donde tú tienes el poder de root. Técnica y teóricamente puedes hacer lo que desees. ¿Tienes los servicios del apache funcionando? ¿están los permisos de los directorios como esperas? ¿cómo estás configurando el dominio del sitio disponible y del sitio habilitado?

Comment: Apache, está funcionando. Los directorios tienen : drwxrwxrwx  root  root. Los archivos: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root rootcd ..

Comment: Seguí la documentación de linode y apache2, para crear el sitio en /var/www/html/syscon32.cl/public_html, donde se subieron los directorios y archivos, en /etc/apache2/sites-avalaible, se creo el archivo syscon32.cl.conf. No sé que más puedo aportar para conseguir ayuda.